# How to reset dropdown box in jquery (select2)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following code:

https://jsfiddle.net/rmxpq2z0/

```
<div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
<div id="quote-form" class="quote-form">
<div class="container">
<div class="range range-xs-center range-lg-right">
  <div class="cell-xs-10 cell-sm-8 cell-lg-5 text-left offset-top-0">
    <div class="inset-lg-left-70">
      <div class="quote-form-body">
        <a href="" data-custom-toggle="quote-form" class="close icon icon-xxs fa-close text-white"></a>
        <div>
          <h3 class="text-bold">Get a FREE Quote!</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="offset-top-25">
          <p>Please select your repair from the drop down boxes for an instant quote.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="offset-top-20">
          <div class="form-group">
            <select data-minimum-results-for-search="Infinity" class="form-control select-filter" id="console">
              <option value="selectconsole">Select My Console</option>
              <option value="ps4">PS4</option>
              <option value="xboxone">Xbox One</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <select data-minimum-results-for-search="Infinity" class="form-control select-filter" id="model">
            </select>
          </div>
          <a href="calculate.html" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Get My Quote</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>




<script>

ps4models = new Array("Select My Model", "PS4 (Release Model)", "PS4 Slim", "PS4 Pro");
xboxonemodels = new Array("Select My Model", "Xbox One (Release Model)", "Xbox One Slim", "Xbox One Scorpio");

populateSelect();

$(function() {

  $('#console').change(function() {
    populateSelect();
  });

});

function populateSelect() {
  console = $('#console').val();
  $('#model').empty();
  $('#model').html('');

  if (console == 'ps4') {
    ps4models.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#model').append('<option>' + t + '</option>');
      $('#model').trigger("chosen:updated");
      $('#model').find('option:first').attr('selected', 'selected');
    });
  }

  if (console == 'xboxone') {
    xboxonemodels.forEach(function(t) {
      $('#model').append('<option>' + t + '</option>');
      $('#model').trigger("chosen:updated");
      $('#model').find('option:first').attr('selected', 'selected');
    });
  }

</script>
```

It works perfectly in the jsfiddle, but when I post the code to the website, it doesn't work.

It DOES populate the dropdown box, but it won't auto select the first option in the second box, and it won't remove any previous option that was selected.

For example, if I select an option in the first box, the second box stays empty until I select something. The first option should be auto selected. Also if I select something in the second box, and then change the selection in the first box, the second box option stays there, instead of being reset.

It is the EXACT same code, no changes at all. Is it possible the CSS is interfering with it?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

### UPDATE

Thanks to DanielH! It turns out the template was using Select2 jquery plugin. His code worked perfectly.

Comment: Its works perfect on website, try clear your browser cache.

Comment: check your console

Comment: @imSayan It does populate the box, but it doesn't work as intended (explained in original post)

Comment: @this.girish I don't see anything obviously wrong in the console :-(

Comment: You are using select2 could you show me the code you use to config the dropdown?

Comment: @DanielH The whole website was a template which I am adapting to my needs. Where would I find the config code? I don't see any select2 js file

Comment: @Chris do you have a github for your repo?

Comment: @Chris are you able to add js code? cus It can also be done with js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Solution 1:

Since you are using select2, add `$('#model').change();` at the end of your **console** dropdown's select2 config should trigger the update every time you update the **model** dropdown list.

#### Solution 2:

If you have no control over the select2 or not sure where to find it, the following also gonna work, add a onchange event to the parent dropdown console:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
   $('#console').on('change', function(){
      $('#model').val('selectmodel');
      $('#model').change();
   })
});
```

Comment: Thanks Daniel! I'm not sure where to find the select2 config, so I'm going to try Solution 2. Where should I add the code?

Comment: @Chris js code for that page? or and HTML before the end of `</body>` tag

Comment: I just tried it in the existing script, and in its own script but it didn't seem to do anything :-(

Comment: @Chris if you search this in your project what you get `inViewport jQuery plugin`

Comment: @Chris I found it in your source, if you put my updated code there should work

Comment: The inviewport jquery plugin was something I added myself for the twitter animated counters. Not related to this

Comment: I have put a comment saying "DanielH" at the top of the script

Comment: @Chris yes, put the code there `$('#console').on('change', function(){ $('#model').val('selectmodel'); $('#model').change(); })`

Comment: @Chris ok, use the updated code to below that comment

Comment: @Chris cool, it is working. then you can try to move that into one place with your other js code. good luck